# How get access to the game-events data in sc2reader?

Tags: python, class, input

I'd like to process game data per multi frame/seconds in StarCraft2. I don't know how can I use [PlayerStatsEvent()](https://github.com/GraylinKim/sc2reader/blob/master/sc2reader/events/tracker.py#L79) to get access to the game data for each frame. PlayerStatsEvent() My code is as follow:

```
from sc2reader.events import tracker
from sc2reader.factories import SC2Factory

path1 = 'D:/Data/sorted/bronze/'
replays = sc2.load_replays(path1)
for r in replays:
    if r.type == '1v1':
        tracker_event = tracker.PlayerStatsEvent(???)
```

The PlayerStatsEvent() has a definition as follow:

```
class PlayerStatsEvent(TrackerEvent):

def __init__(self, frames, data, build):
    super(PlayerStatsEvent, self).__init__(frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to use `PlayerStatsEvent` by yourself - the events are generated / emitted by the framework when you're iterating over the replay you've loaded. You should be able to find these events through `replay.events`, and then filter events with `isinstance`.

Comment: Thanks. The `replay.events` is a list of `PacketEvent`, and none of them include `PlayerStatsEvent()`.

Comment: @Ynr Try `.tracker_events` instead. The whole structure of the engine is detailed at [https://github.com/GraylinKim/sc2reader/blob/master/sc2reader/engine/engine.py](GitHub)

Comment: I tried replay.tracker_events too, but it return an empty list for replays.